# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: UserService.authenticate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, authorization, knex.js

im trying to implement a basic auth to my api project with knex express and mysql.

i have the following functions

```
const users = [{ id:1, username:'selia', password:'fullservice'}]



function authenticate({ username, password}) {
    const user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password === password)
    if(user) {
        const {password, ...userWithoutPassword} = user
        return userWithoutPassword
    }
}

module.exports  = authenticate
```

and

```
const userService = require('../users/user.service.js')





async function basicAuth(req,res,next){
    // checando basic auth
    if(!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic') === -1) {
        return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Header de Autorizacao nao encontrado'})
    }

    //verificando basuc auth

    const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split('')[1]
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii')
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':')
    const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password})
    if (!user){
        return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Usuario e/ou senha invalidos'})
    }

    //atribuindo usuario no objeto da requisicao
    req.user = user

    next();
}

module.exports = basicAuth
```

and this is my index

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const basicAuth = require('./helpers/basic-auth')

const app = express()
app.use(basicAuth)
app.use(routes)






app.listen(3333, ()=> console.log('Server is running'))
```

when i run it i get this error

```
(node:7488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: userService.authenticate is not a function
    at basicAuth (/home/matheus/projeto/src/helpers/basic-auth.js:18:30)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/matheus/projeto/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
(node:7488) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7488) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i get this error when i do a get request on insomnia

i belive that this has to do with my async function but i cant figure out how to fix that

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering how you exported and imported the function, this line is not correct:

```js
const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password})
```

It should just be:

```js
const user = await userService({ username, password})
```

Because your `user.service.js` module exports a function, NOT an object with an `authenticate` property.

Comment: your logic is correct thanks, i did diferently but it works too

i changed this 
´´´
module.exports  = authenticate
´´´

to this

module.exports  = {authenticate}